# How to edit env variables,bash: dotnet: command not found?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

I installed latest Windows 10,when I run from gitbash

```
$ dotnet --version
bash: dotnet: command not found
```

But req query shows that I have .NET Framework
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\CDF\v4.0
    HttpNamespaceReservationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NetTcpPortSharingInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    NonHttpActivationInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1
    SMSvcHostPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    WMIInstalled    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084
```

How to edit system env variables?

Comment: `dotnet` is part of .NET Core, not .NET Framework. You need to install the [.NET Core SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks,please add answer,that would kelp beginners.